# In app purchase not work

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I use this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases for create purchases in my app.

From time to time this code is working or not working. I know it sounds funny, but this is my problem.

For example: First start app (all items download and shows in table and i have available to purchase any of this), but at the next time (for example second start) I get an error on this line:

```
SKProduct *product = [[InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper].products objectAtIndex:0];
```

The error is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException' index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Comment: In addition to Vince's comment: Please provide more insight on what error is going on and also describe what you tried so far so nobody wastes his time on things you already tried.

Comment: Message in "Not purchased: com.company.sb.pack5" (but this message showing time to time)

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander you should edit your question to include that detail, not put it in comments where it might get missed. I have added it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem I solved after make hard reset for my device.

Comment: what's meaning of "after make hard reset for my device."? Setting - > reset --> Reset all settings?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid this kind of crash just put a condition before processing the product like this:

```
if ([[InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper].products count] >0)
{
   SKProduct *product = [[InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper].products objectAtIndex:0];
   //product processing goes here
}
else
{
   NSLog (@"Warning: no products returned");
}
```

Comment: hello! yes, this is right checking, but why I don't have products after calling method - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response?

Comment: this is hard to say without more background. maybe if you post a code of delegate methods and of a method where you create your request. Before you do that be sure to make all product identifiers unreadble - overwrite them with FFFFFF or something. Also make sure to check this guide, it shouldn't take you more than 15 minutes: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/StoreKitGuide.pdf

Comment: thanks for all. yes my question is pretty common. tutorial of the ray wenderlich usually work excellent (and it work excellent too, but time to time). i think this is my mistake. thanks for reference!

Answer (score 1):

use this Code when you use the payment method.....like payment button pressed

```
NSLog(@"Products - %@",[IAPClockDietHelper sharedHelper].products);
```

You found , when You start App First time then You have products valve...and when You use app Second time then Products have NULL Value....So Your Application is Crash ...check ..

Comment: NSLog(@"Products - %@",[IAPClockDietHelper sharedHelper].products); now - for this log I get no item in NSArray products. but why this is not always crash?

Comment: At one point I get full array of the my item and else at next time I have no one elements in my products array.

Comment: see this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324596/storekit-skproductsrequest-crash

Comment: My method - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response is executed, but I do not get no value in response.

Comment: please check all Conecpt http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/