# how to retain self in ARC mode, such as SKProductsRequest, retain self in start method then release after response come back?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, automatic-ref-counting, retain

See the following code sample (ARC mode), how SKProductsRequest retain itself to wait response come back? I mean in ARC mode you can't write [self retain], how does SKProductsRequest retain self in start method, then release self after response? As you know delegate is always weak.

SKProductsRequest is just an example here, now I need to such a service class and have no idea on how to retain self when request send out then release myself when response come back, anyone who has idea please share and discuss together, thanks in advance.

```
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:set];
productRequest = productsRequest;
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];
```

**PS:
Regarding objc_setAssociatedObject, external long live object needed to keep retain relationship.**

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(externalLiveObj, &kRetainSelfKey, self, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Are you asking how Apple implements `SKProductsRequest` so that it stays alive during the request? Or are you asking how to write your own class that uses `SKProductsRequest` so that your object stays alive during the `SKProductsRequest` operation?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, my key point is how does an object keep alive in async action? SKProductsRequest is just an example here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give yourself an instance variable.  Set it to `self` when you start the request:

```
@implementation MyRequestDelegate {
    MyRequestDelegate *me;
}

- (void)startProductsRequest {
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:set];
    productRequest = productsRequest;
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
    me = self;  // this retains self
}
```

Then in the delegate method, set it back to `nil`:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    // process response here, and then...
    me = nil;
}
```

Comment: To make this idea work with several "users" at once I'd use a `NSMutableArray` to which `self` can be pushed/popped.

Comment: Great, I see, the key point here is let a container to add/remove self instance to keep retained. Thanks.

Comment: Is this solution going to work if the optimization is enabled (like in the release version)? Variable 'me' is set but never used. The compiler can very well remove these lines of the code. The solution with a container (e.g. NSMutableArray) should be the preferred one.

Comment: Yes, it will work even under optimization. The compiler cannot remove the setting of the `me` variable because it knows setting a strong instance variable has a side effect, and also because other code can use `object_getIvar` or `ivar_getOffset` to get the value of the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe SKProductsRequest uses NSNotification stuff and/or NSRunLoop. This crash log [StoreKit SKProductsRequest Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3324596/629118) implies that.

```
1   StoreKit                        0x00003e18 -[SKProductsRequest handleFinishResponse:returningError:] + 40
2   StoreKit                        0x000050c4 -[SKRequest _requestFinishedNotification:] + 152
3   Foundation                      0x00019b9a _nsnote_callback + 150
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0006c2de __CFXNotificationPost_old + 390
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0001ab32 _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 122
6   Foundation                      0x000048e4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
```

So I guess, in SKProductsRequest,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self ...
```

The defaultCenter object retains SKProductsRequest object.

**EDIT**

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self doesn't retain self observer, it is weak reference.

Eh, sorry for that. (I never noticed it, thanks!) But the basic idea is still the same. For example, NSNotificationCenter -addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: can retain an object via the block. NSRunLoop + NSTimer as well. NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter, NSRunLoop the main loop on the main thread, and so on, there are retained object by the framework or the OS. So those objects can retain your object.

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self doesn't retain self observer, it is weak reference.