# iOS UIWebView in-app purchase not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to achieve an in app purchase from a UIWebView:

index.html

```
<html><body>

<script>
    function purchase() {
        var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        iframe.setAttribute("src", "purchase");
        document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    };
</script>

<br><br><br><button onclick="purchase()">Purchase!</button>

</body></html>
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PurchaseBackend.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    _webview.delegate = self;
    [_webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    if ([request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"purchase"].location == NSNotFound) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        PurchaseBackend *pb = [[PurchaseBackend alloc] init];
        [pb purchaseClick];

        return NO;
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

PurchaseBackend.h

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface PurchaseBackend : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

-(void)purchaseClick;

@end
```

PurchaseBackend.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import "PurchaseBackend.h"

@implementation PurchaseBackend

#define productID @"com.organization.MonthSubscription"

- (void)purchaseClick{
    NSLog(@"User clicked purchase button");

    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
        NSLog(@"User can make payments");

        //If you have more than one in-app purchase, and would like
        //to have the user purchase a different product, simply define
        //another function and replace kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier with
        //the identifier for the other product

        SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:productID]];
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [productsRequest start];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"User cannot make payments due to parental controls");
        //this is called the user cannot make payments, most likely due to parental controls
    }
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if(count > 0){
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Products Available!");
        [self purchase:validProduct];
    }
    else if(!validProduct){
        NSLog(@"No products available");
        //this is called if your product id is not valid, this shouldn't be called unless that happens.
    }
}

- (void)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
        switch(transaction.transactionState){
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
            //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
            break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            //this is called when the user has successfully purchased the package (Cha-Ching!)
            [self paid]; //you can add your code for what you want to happen when the user buys the purchase here
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");
            break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
            //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            //called when the transaction does not finish
            if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                //the user cancelled the payment ;(
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)paid{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"PAID"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"User Paid, state saved");
}

@end
```

Result
[image]

xcode console

`2015-12-31 13:13:26.120 AppName[392:102559] User clicked purchase button`
`2015-12-31 13:13:26.144 AppName[392:102559] User can make payments`
`(lldb)`

Help!

**UPDATE:**

Updated ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PurchaseBackend.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

PurchaseBackend *purchaseBackend;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    _webview.delegate = self;
    [_webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    if ([request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"purchase"].location == NSNotFound) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        purchaseBackend = [[PurchaseBackend alloc] init];
        [purchaseBackend purchaseClick];

        return NO;
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Thanks to helpful comments, I discovered the cause of the memory crash - the PurchaseBackend delegate object was being deallocated while the storekit framework was still using it. I've updated `ViewController.m` as shown above, but now instead of a crash, nothing happens after "User can make payments" is printed. I put a breakpoint in `didReceiveResponse` and it does not execute.

Comment: Start by visiting http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: Is `com.organization.MonthSubscription` defined as an IAP on the Apple servers?

Comment: Yes GlennRay - although I have changed the productID on this post to keep it anonymous

Comment: Thanks to the tutorial provided by maddy, I discovered the crash was caused by the PurchaseBackend object being deallocated before the SKProductsRequest was done with it as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324596/storekit-skproductsrequest-crash

Comment: It's still not working though - see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you may have a memory problem, the "purchaseBackend" object seems to be deallocated before it has a chance to catch the didReceiveResponse callback.

Try to add a strong property for it and be sure your "viewController" is not deallocated itself.

It would probably be a good idea to transform purchaseBackend in a singleton in order to avoid this kind of problems

You may have a look at this tutorial about ARC in order to better understand how memory is managed in iOS : [Beginning ARC in iOS 5 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1).

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it was helpful, but what really helped was implementing the following method. With this I was able to see the "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" error `- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}`